# Jquery scrollTop resets to original position after scrolling

Tags: jquery, html

The **contact** location.hash works but the **about** will just reset to the original position in which you refresh the page from. Any ideas?

This is not the entire HTML, just where the page will be scrolling to so imagine more content above

```js
if (location.hash == "#about") {
 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".landing-section").offset().top -50
    }, 500);
}

if (location.hash == "#contact") {
 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".list-section").offset().top - 50
    }, 800);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-item about-item"><a class="ripple" href="/#about">About</a></div>
<div class="nav-item contact-item"><a class="ripple" href="/#contact">Contact</a></div>

 <div class="landing-section">
  <div style="padding-bottom: 30px" class="section-left">
   <div class="section-text">
    <h1 class="section-title">About</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-section">
   <ul class="landing-list">
       <li class="landing-list-item">
        <p class="landing-list-text">
     "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
     </p>
       </li>
       <li class="landing-list-item">
        <p class="landing-list-text">
     "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
     </p>
       </li>
       <li class="landing-list-item">
        <p class="landing-list-text">
     "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
     </p>
       </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML and CSS to the snippet?

Comment: can you include the HTML ?

Comment: added @DacreDenny

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no `.landing-section` ro `.contact` in your code, also notice that code as is, will run on page load, not after any event (like a click)

Answer (score 0):

Where is the script declared? Are you executing this code after the page has fully loaded?

Ideally, you'll want to do this kind of thing once the DOM is fully loaded. Either by doing this:

```
$.ready(function() {
    //Your code here
})
```

Or at the end of your `<body>` tag, to ensure the elements (eg ".contact", ".landing-section") are present in the DOM before the script attempts to scroll to them.

Comment: @nick can you confirm that you're HTML/DOM has fully loaded before you run your script? Are you running your script from in $.ready( ... ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to scroll to an element with a class name `.contact`, but none of your elements have such a class.

I added an element with a `.contact` class. I also tied anchor clicks to the action that you want to happen when an anchor is clicked (scroll).

Below is the updated code with some added robustness to your JavaScript, which now runs on document ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      if (hash == "#about") {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(".landing-section").offset().top - 50
        }, 500);
      }

      if (hash == "#contact") {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(".contact").offset().top - 50
        }, 800);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-item about-item"><a class="ripple" href="#about">About</a></div>
<div class="nav-item contact-item"><a class="ripple" href="#contact">Contact</a></div>

<div class="landing-section">
  <div style="padding-bottom: 30px" class="section-left">
    <div class="section-text">
      <h1 class="section-title">About</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-section">
    <ul class="landing-list">
      <li class="landing-list-item">
        <p class="landing-list-text">
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="landing-list-item">
        <p class="landing-list-text">
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </p>
      </li>
      <li class="landing-list-item">
        <p class="landing-list-text">
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<h1 class="contact">Contact</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the page resetting to the top was because it was scrolling down and once the page had fully loaded it would go back to the top. To fix this I simply added an element to Jquery to wait till the code for the page had loaded.

```js
$(window).bind("load", function() {
 if (location.hash == "**location hash**") {
 $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".**div class**").offset().top - 75
    }, 800);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This then waits until everything has loaded, then proceeds to scroll down.